# Block-distraction apps for iOS

Tags: ios

I want to write an iOS app that helps users concentrate on their work by preventing them from accessing particular apps on their devices for particular amount of time.

I googled around and found some "help-to-concentrate" iOS apps, but they mostly just help us to keep track of our usage of the phone (amount of time we spent on the phone, number of times we turn on the phone...). So, I do not know whether it is possible write an iOS app that can block some other apps on the device for a period of time or not?

If it is possible, can you please suggest me any keywords or Swift libraries that support this task?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible to write anything like that for iOS. Just forget it.

Comment: Just a line that "It is not possible". iOS will not allow you to access different app's metadata or access process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **Apple** doesn't allow any app to access the files of other apps, it is impossible. It's just a safety measure for the users. Just use another practice to keep users "concentrated".